# Best way to use CSV files in Java

Tags: java, csv, sorting

Im having trouble with the best approach to reading a CSV file in order to extract and compare certain things in it. The file is made up of strings, and I need to keep track if there are duplicated items. Here is what I have so far.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.FileReader;

import java.io.IOException;

public class CSVReader {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

  String csvFile = "Cchallenge.csv";

  String line = "";

  String cvsSplitBy = ",";

     try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {

         while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

            // use comma as separator

           String[] country = line.split(cvsSplitBy);


 } catch (IOException e) {

     e.printStackTrace();

 }

 }

 }
```

So I made an array called country with all the data. But when I go to print out the arrays length, it gives my a lot of different arrays with varying sizes. I am having a hard time traversing the arrays and extracting the duplicates. Any ideas will help, thanks.

Comment: You see you're not saving the `country` data anywhere. It is getting over-written every time it reads a new line. The varying size is most probably because of the varying number of columns in each row in your csv. Add an image of the csv if possible ?

Comment: if you are working with `CSV Files` I would recommend this: https://super-csv.github.io/super-csv/

Answer (score 0):

If you simply wish to get a list of the items without any duplicates, then you could collect the items into a set, as sets do not allow duplicate items:

```
Set<String> items = new HashSet<>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        items.addAll(Arrays.asList(line.split(cvsSplitBy)));
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

If you also want to keep track of the duplicates, you could use another set and add items into it if they already exist in the first set. This would be an easy feat to accomplish, as the `add` method of `Set` returns a boolean in regards to if the set already contained the specified element or not:

```
Set<String> items = new HashSet<>();
Set<String> duplicates = new HashSet<>();

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        for (String item : line.split(cvsSplitBy)) {
            if (items.add(item)) {
                continue;
            }
            duplicates.add(item);
        }
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```